# Is there a Arduino UI library that provides dialog box and button functionality at a minimum?

Tags: tft, ui

I have been looking at the Arduino TFT Library and it supports all the bits and pieces for making a simple display, but I am looking for something a little higher level that has primitive dialog box and button capability, and presumably, the ability to layer the display so I can push and pop display elements.  Is there a higher level GUI library for Arduino TFT displays?

Comment: a quick search found this ...https://youtu.be/UEKrithNr1g

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this library. Will this do all that you want?

https://github.com/AndreiDegtiarev/AWind

I have not tried it yet but I would like to.

Edit:

I just remembered this https://github.com/ImpulseAdventure/GUIslice
https://github.com/ImpulseAdventure/GUIslice/wiki

A lightweight GUI framework for embedded displays

The library supports creation of multiple pages of buttons, text, images, checkboxes, sliders and other graphics primitives. New UI / widget types can be created easily.

It works with many existing TFT libraries. There also is a drag & drop builder application.  https://github.com/ImpulseAdventure/GUIslice-Builder